# Data and string comparison with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm a beginner with node.js and I'm willing to create a TCP server which would give me different answers depending on what it receives.

Here's the server side :

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
    console.log('socket opened');
    c.setEncoding('utf8');
    c.on('end', function() {
        console.log('connection/socket closed');
    });
    c.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Data:'+data);
        if(data.toString() == "open"){
            c.write('Answer: opened');
        }else if(data.toString() === "add"){
            c.write('Answer: added');
        }else if(data.toString() === "process"){
             c.write('Answer: processed');
        }
    });
});

server.listen(8080, function() { // start server (port 8080)
    console.log('server started');
});
```

I simply use telnet to try and see if my code is working.
Basically I want the server to answer 'opened' if I send him 'open', 'added' if I send 'add' ...
I don't know why but it wont work.
I've been trying for an hour already and I'm sure that must be some simple mistake I made but now I can't see anything that would cause this simple echo server not to work properly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I know it's later, but there is a better answer, and I found this googling a similar problem. So here are my 2 cents.

To properly catch all cases (and not just the quirks specific to this single case) you should just use the [`trim()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) method

```
if (data.toString().trim() === 'open') {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I was using double quotes instead of single ones, does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is **OK**. When you use telnet, you send text messages out by hitting ENTER key. The text received by the sever ends with `'\r\n'`. So you should compare two strings like this:

```
if (data.toString() === 'open\r\n') {
  //...
}
```

Comment: ... and then somebody will use `netcat`, and the app would break... It should really be `data.toString().replace(/\r?\n$/, '') === 'open'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison and response in html(javascript)

```
var diff_match_patch = require('googlediff');
var dmp = new diff_match_patch();

function compareString(){
    var leftHandSideObject = JSON.stringify(req.body[0]);
    var rightHandSideObject = JSON.stringify(req.body[1]);
    var ms_start = (new Date()).getTime();
    var d = dmp.diff_main(leftHandSideObject, rightHandSideObject);
    var ms_end = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (true) {
        dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(d);
    }
    res.status(200).json(ds);
}
```